# Make text fit the remaining space and keep the same motion effect

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I have a Next js project in the following structure:

```
.
├── media
│   └── img.jpg
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   └── AnimatedCharacters.js
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── _app.js
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── index_.js
│   └── styles
│       └── global.css
└── tailwind.config.js
```

The content of the files is as follows:
package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.5",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5"
  }
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const { fontfamily } = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        poppins: ["var(--font-poppins)"],
      },
      colors: {
        dark: "#1b1b1b",
        light: "#f5f5f5",
        primary: "#B63E96", // 240,86,199
        primaryDark: "#58E6D9", // 80,230,217
        white: "#fff",
        light_purple: "#8490ff",
        light_white: "#f9f9ff",
        text_color: "#777777",
      },
    },
    borderWidth: {
      1: "1px",
      2: "2px",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

src/styles/global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

src/pages/_app.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import "../styles/global.css";
import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";

const poppins = Poppins({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-poppins",
  weight: ["100", "200", "400", "300", "500", "600", "700"],
});

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={`${poppins.variable} font-poppins`}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

src/pages/index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import profilepicture from "../../media/img.jpg";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className="w-full h-auto pl-14 pr-14 flex bg-light_white text-black">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full pt-20 pb-20">
          <div className="flex-1 pr-14">
            <p className="text-text_color mb-2">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <p className="text-text_color mb-2">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <p className="text-text_color mb-2">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="w-80 h-80">
            <Image
              src={profilepicture}
              alt="bird"
              className="w-full h-full object-cover rounded-full"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When running `npm run dev`, this works as expected; the text takes the space left after the image is well placed.

[image]

In addition, when I resize the window, the text adapts to the space as well.

[image]

However, when I added the `AnimatedCharacters.js` component, the text stakes as much as it needs of space which even exceeds the width of the screen when I resize it.

Here the code:
src/components/AnimatedCharacters.js

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function AnimatedCharacters({
  text,
  className = "",
  reverse = false,
}) {
  // splitting text into letters
  const letters = Array.from(text);

  // Variants for Container
  const container = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    visible: (i = 1) => ({
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        staggerChildren: 0.02,
        delayChildren: 0.03 * i,
        staggerDirection: reverse ? -1 : 1, // Adjust staggerDirection based on reverse prop
      },
    }),
  };

  // Variants for each letter
  const child = {
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      transition: {
        type: "spring",
        damping: 12,
        stiffness: 100,
      },
    },
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: reverse ? 20 : -20, // Adjust initial x position based on reverse prop
      y: 10,
      transition: {
        type: "spring",
        damping: 12,
        stiffness: 100,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      className={className}
      variants={container}
      initial="hidden"
      animate="visible"
    >
      {letters.map((letter, index) => (
        <motion.span variants={child} key={index}>
          {letter === " " ? "\u00A0" : letter}
        </motion.span>
      ))}
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

And this is how index.js looks like after adding the new component:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import profilepicture from "../../media/img.jpg";
import AnimatedCharacters from "../components/AnimatedCharacters";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
      </Head>
      <main className="w-full h-auto pl-14 pr-14 flex bg-light_white text-black">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full pt-20 pb-20">
          <div className="pr-14">
            <AnimatedCharacters
              text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
              do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
              className="text-text_color mb-2 overflow-hidden flex"
            />
            <AnimatedCharacters
              text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
              do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
              reverse
              className="text-text_color mb-2 overflow-hidden flex"
            />
            <AnimatedCharacters
              text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
              do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
              className="text-text_color mb-2 overflow-hidden flex"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="w-80 h-80">
            <Image
              src={profilepicture}
              alt="bird"
              className="w-full h-full object-cover rounded-full"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a link to [a video record](https://imgur.com/8CLqxno) I just made.

Is there a way to make the text fit whatever space left after placing the image and apply the motion effect to the formatted text line by line (i.e nth line appears from the left, n+1th line appears from the right)?

I am using Tailwind CSS and framer-motion

Answer (score 0):

if u managed to make the text wrap inside the div

there is a problem in this line `{letter === " " ? "\u00A0" : letter}`
because now every letter is in a **span** so lets say the word **text**
if you resized the page it might not be displayed **text** it might be like:

**te


xt**

so before you split text into letters  `const letters = Array.from(text);`

your gonna have to separate every word in a span

code:

```
export default function App() {

  const text =
  "separate- every- word- with- any- symbol- also- with- a- white- space";
let letterInd = 0;

return (
  <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }} className="pt-20">
    {text
      .replaceAll("-", `${"\u00A0"}`)
      .split(" ")
      .map((word, i) => (
        <div key={"word" + i}>
          {word.split("").map((letter, j) => (
            <RevealLetter i={letterInd++} key={"letter" + j}>
              {letter}
            </RevealLetter>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
  </div>
);
}

const RevealLetter = (props) => {
const { children, i } = props;

return (
  <motion.span
    initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
    transition={{ delay: i * 0.02 }}
  >
    {children}
  </motion.span>
);
};
```

you have to separate every word in the `const text` with a symbol so you can use it to replace it with a space between every word

1. what i did is the `text` i replaced the symbol with a space `${"\u00A0"}`
2. i used split and the value is the space `" "` to separate every word
3. i used split again to separate every letter in evey word and put it in `motion.span`
4. i also added `letterIndex` that getting increased by +1